# Сохранение запроса QUERY в репозитории в EXCEL файл

Tags: java, postgresql, excel, spring-boot

Репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT pp.id, pp.created_dt, au.username, ss.name, pp.amount,\n" +
            "REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Удачно') AS status, pp.account,\n" +
            "pp.external_id, COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'Не определен') AS external_status\n" +
            "FROM payments AS pp\n" +
            "INNER JOIN auth_user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
            "INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
            "WHERE pp.created_dt::date = (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' day)::date\n" +
            "AND ss.name = 'SomeName' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> findAll();
}
```

Как сохранить результат этой выборки в excel файл?

Никуда его не выводить (я имею ввиду без каких-нибудь респонсов). Просто потом я буду отправлять  этот файл по почте, как отчет.

---

PS формат .csv пойдет. Я реализовывал сохранение запроса в формат .csv, но без репозитория, просто через String QUERY = ... Но мне нужен объект. Если сможете подсказать как сделать на основе репозитория .csv тоже будет хорошо

Comment: У вас есть список `List<User>` и вы его хотите сохранить в excel файл, правильно? Если так, то вопрос не имеет отношения к БД. Далее, какой формат нужен? excel поддерживает много форматов. csv годится?

Comment: @Alexander Зачем вы правите вопрос из под новой уч. записи, а где старая?

Comment: здесь возникает много вопросов... ну, к примеру, у меня одно из полей класса - дата. в каком формате она должны быть выведена в файл? а если есть другой вложенный объект? я бы предложить создать интерфейс с методом toCsv() и реализовывать его для каждого имплементирующего класса по аналогии с toString() только с разделителем в виде ';', а дальше нужно просто склеивать результат выполнения такого метода построчно с разделителем в виде перемещения строки и в файл. вот и все. разумеется склеивать нужно в отдельном классе, принимающем список объектов типа этого интерфейса